# Convert plain text in to HTML

Tags: jquery, text

I have a script with which at a certain point I'm getting HTML(data) with Ajax call. I have to turn this HTML in to plain text like this:

```
$("#div").text(data);
```

I now want to turn this around and make the text HTML again. I there an easy Jquery method of doing this? I tried:

```
$("#div").text(data).end().html();
```

No luck.

Comment: Depends on what HTML you want to turn it to.  It can't read your mind, since you removed the HTML.  Why not store the AJAX html in a variable and call later?

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: @Youss, sorry, I misunderstood your question. Do you really want to put the markup in an element as text then immediately override it with the same markup as HTML elements?

Comment: # popnoodles Just HTML

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Yes, see my comment on answer Steve Fenton

Comment: By turn into HTML what do you mean? The text is HTML, do you mean an object?

Comment: @popnoodles The Jquery part is turning the source code in to plain text, so basically you can see the source code on the website

Comment: I think what you're after is what I posted 10 minutes ago. Edited the fiddle to make it really obvious.

Comment: Thanks but Steve Fenton answered first and his code also make sence. Both codes; yours and accepted dont work for me because the problem was different after all then what my question was about. However Im not going to delete question because I believe it could help others in there quest for similar problems (regarding the question that is..)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to hold onto the original response to do this...

```
$("#hiddendiv").html(data);
$("#div").text(data);
```

Then you could get it back out...

```
var html = $("#hiddendiv").html();
```

**Update based on comment...**

You can remove that element before you display it...

```
var html = $(data);
$('#cookiediv', html).hide();
$('#div').html(html);
```

Where the cookie message has `id="cookiediv"` - you may need to adjust the selector to get to this div, but it is almost certainly possible to grab it.

Comment: That doesnt work in my case. To brake the problem down: The webpage Im getting data from is showing a cookie message and hiding all the content. So the var=HTML will only get me the cookie window. However I have noticed that if I get the text() I get all the text of the website, so now if I covert it to HTML I get the complete website without the annoying cookie message.

Comment: I have added a suggestion for that scenario. If you can show me the raw data you get back (for example on a JSFiddle) I can be more specific.

Comment: Im starting to think I have starting a bad question...This is the website: http://telegraaf.nl There is no cookie window, Its a complete different url, visitors are being directed to other url first...

Comment: Which is weird, because getting text only seems to get the text of the main website

Comment: Hi, removing #tmg-consent wont do it because its on a different url I realize now....

Answer (score 4):

The html function that you're using in your question can also take an argument. Read all about it here: http://api.jquery.com/html

Basically all you need to do is

```
var div = $(yourdiv);
div.html(div.text())
```

such as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/273Jx/

Answer (score 3):

```
$.fn.toHtml=function(){
   return $(this).html($(this).text())
}
```

then

```
$('#div').toHtml()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/fcn9d/

Comment: By far the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean take the text and make it working HTML. **[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BG8Uh/1)**

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var data='<a href="blah">blah</a>';
$('#div').text(data);
alert('ready...'); // just making you see the html
$('#div').html($('#div').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it directly to jQuery itself (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). It will take the raw HTML string and attempt to parse it into a new DOM fragment.